# Angular $routeProvider based on user role

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I would like to register routes in my angular application based on the roles of the user, can I do something like:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
    .config(function($routeProvider, $http){
        $routeProvider.when('/home',{
           templateUrl: '/home.html',
           controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        });
        $http.get('/user')
            .success(function(user){
                if (user.admin){
                    $routeProvider.when('/dashboard, {
                        templateUrl: '/dashboard.html',
                        controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
                    });
                }
            });
    });
```

But in the `config` method I can't use the `$http` service, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).  It is a much more feature-rich state-based routing system for Angular.  It solves your problem by allowing you to make a model request at the moment of your state change, and return a promise so that when you get your model, you can either continue or change state again.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem.
There is my solution :

```
'use strict';

angular.module('theAppName')
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
          .when('/check', { // the role has to be 'not_confirmed'
            templateUrl: 'app/account/check/check.html', 
            controller: 'CheckCtrl'
            });
    })

.run(function ($rootScope, $location, Auth) {
    // Redirect to '/' if the role is not 'not_confirmed'
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next) {
      Auth.getUserRoleInAsync(function(role) {
        if (next.$$route.originalPath === '/check' && role !== 'not_confirmed') {
          $location.path('/');
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

If you don't precise the route tested, it will be test for all routes. So you need to use `next.$$route.originalPath` .

In the Auth service file :

```
  getUserRoleInAsync: function(cb) {
    if(currentUser.hasOwnProperty('$promise')) {
      currentUser.$promise.then(function(data) {
        cb(data.role);
      }).catch(function() {
        cb(false);
      });
    } else {
      cb(false);
    }
  },
```

I'm waiting some feedback about this.

Comment: In the end I found more easy and practical using the HATEOAS (and hypermedia) concepts in my application. In this way the server says what the user could do, in this way all the authorization logic is on the server and isn't duplicated on the client.